# Lazy loading breaks lightbox

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, lightbox

Using this [*lazy-loading* code](https://fireship.io/snippets/intersection-observer-lazy-load-images), my [lightbox](https://github.com/demtario/hes-gallery) breaks: clicking on an image shows the *lightbox* but without image.

I can see that the lightbox img tag has no `src` value by checking the inspector. I guess the lightbox checks the src before the *lazy-loading* has assigned the attribute and the value to the image.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you share some code it's hard to tell what's going on without observing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the `data-fullsize` parameter mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/demtario/hes-gallery) - if this is set on each `<img>` tag, they should be loaded when the gallery is opened.

An example of how this might look in the HTML (with the lazy-loading example from the link you provided):

```html
<img data-lazy="img/cow.jpeg" data-fullsize="img/cow.jpeg">
```